# Web2Py POST method not working according to example :-(

Tags: python, post, web2py

I am making an API for my web2py app and for the life of me cannot get it to work as shown in the web2pybook:
http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Low-level-API-and-other-recipes

Here is api from the defaults.py:

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    def GET(app_listings,id):
        if not app_listings=='app': raise HTTP(400)
        return dict(app = db.app_listings(id))
    def POST(app_user,device):
        if not app_user=='usr': raise HTTP(400)
        return db.usr.validate_and_insert(device)
    return locals()
```

And here is my url for testing the API:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/default/api/usr/3/
```

My responses are:
400 BAD REQUEST

or if I remove the parameter on the end of the URL:
invalid arguments

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your URL, you are passing "usr" and "3" as the two arguments to the `GET()` function, and that function includes the following line:

```
if not app_listings=='app': raise HTTP(400)
```

Since "usr" != "app", it raises the `HTTP(400)` exception.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but this was the POST request I was working with, and 'usr' was defined there. Is there something I am missing.

Comment: How are you making the POST request?

Comment: I thought but specifying "usr" in the API call that it would have to go through the POST route.

Comment: What would tell the code to use the POST function? There is no logic that says to use POST when request.args(0) is "usr". With the @request.restful decorator, the function called is the one whose name matches the HTTP method of the request. If you want to call the POST() function, you have to make a POST HTTP request. How are you making your API calls?

Comment: I am using a CURL request: curl -d "device=ipone4,1" http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/default/api/usr/

Comment: Well, that is a POST request. But when I try that exact curl request with your exact code, it works fine for me.